# Get global-p values in a svyglm model after multiple imputation

Tags: r, survey, imputation, p-value

I am attempting to fit a multivariate glm model (svyglm function) on a svydesign object (package survey) after multiple imputation (mice function ; then with() and MIcombine() ). I would like to get global p-values for qualitative variable with more than two modalities.

Here is my code :

```
 a = readRDS("E:/..../base.RDS")

 #multiple imputation
 aimp = mice(a, m=10, maxit=5,seed=5)

 #complete data frames extraction
 aimp_list = lapply(1:10, function(n) complete (aimp, action=n))

 #creation of a svydesign object from the imputationList object
 awimp = svydesign(~0,probs=NULL, strata=NULL, data = 
 imputationList(aimp_list),
 weights = aimp_list$weights)

 #fitting of logistic models

 moda = with(awimp, svyglm(outcome~treatment+age, family = 
 quasibinomial))
 modaimp = MIcombine(moda)

 modb = with(awimp, svyglm(outcome~treatment, family = 
 quasibinomial))
 modbimp = MIcombine(modb)

 anova(modaimp, modbimp, method="Wald")
```

Unfortunately this does not work

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?
Many thanks if you can help me

Comment: any chance you could give a minimal reproducible example?  not seeing the p-values from this code from `?anova`  --  `counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12);outcome <- gl(3,1,9);treatment <- gl(3,3);glm.a <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson());glm.b <- glm(counts ~ outcome , family = poisson());anova(glm.a,glm.b)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.